# False Dateformatting while putting in a Class Attribute

Tags: android, simpledateformat

I think I've got a little Problem by getting a Date from a JSON, put it into an Attribute of a Class and get it from it to show it in a string.

The important party of my Class are:

```
Date _begin;
public Date getBegin(){ return this._begin; }
public void setBegin(Date begin){ this._begin = begin; }
```

and I use it with an Testoutput here (the important Part of the JSON loop):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin")); 
String tempDateString = c.getString("begin");
try {  
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = dateFormat.parse(tempDateString);
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    thisData.setBegin(date);
    Log.d("SimpleDateFormat(EventActivity Template)", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
    Log.d("SimpleDateFormat(EventActivity String)", tempDateString); 
    Log.d("SimpleDateFormat(EventActivity Output)", dateFormat.format(thisData.getBegin())); 
} catch (ParseException e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

And the testoutput is:

```
05-28 10:02:31.588: D/SimpleDateFormat(EventActivity Template)(10396): dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
05-28 10:02:31.588: D/SimpleDateFormat(EventActivity String)(10396): 2013-09-07 20:00:00
05-28 10:02:31.588: D/SimpleDateFormat(EventActivity Output)(10396): 05-03-0013 20:00:00
```

Why did I get back the Date in this strange format?

Comment: tempDateString obviously doesn't follow your format. this cannot work.

Comment: for the parse you use the wrong pattern . it should be "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Comment: omg. your right. that 's so obviously. sorry, maybee i need a coffee.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add 1900 to year then add it with date and then the currect value and format of date returns.